# Internet inaccessible on Laptop but works on PCs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan, ethernet

In our small company we have laptops as well as PCs connected to a Belkin router with a 2mbps Broadband Internet. The PCs are connected through LAN cables and laptops through WLAN. 
The problem is that most of the time the laptops cant access internet. The websites don't load in browser giving the Problem Loading Page error, although in the task bar the router shows "internet access"(windows 7). This happens 90% of the time. But the two PCs connected(over ethernet) never get this error. Websites always load up in the PC. 
I am guessing it has something to do with the difference in Ethernet and WLAN protocols.
Once we tried connecting the Laptops too with ethernet cable, but the problem persisted.
Is there anything I can do to improve Internet Access on the laptops?

Comment: While the laptops where connected with a cable, where the wireless connections disabled?

Comment: Yes, when the laptops were connected with cables, wifi was disconnected

Comment: It doesn't make any sense why the laptops are showing this behavior, even if they're connected directly. They have no problem connecting at home or other networks? Is there perhaps a Windows domain-server with DHCP&DNS-service?

Comment: Do the laptops browse the Internet properly if connected at a different location (not the company network), like a public WIFI hotspot?

Comment: @CharlieRB The laptops show the same behavior while wired...

Comment: @Ariaan That's not what I asked. What I DID ask can help determine if the issue is with the laptop or the network.

Comment: The laptops have no issue connecting to networks at home and other places.

Comment: @Ariaan how do I check if there is a Windows domain-server with DHCP&DNS-service?